Do these two different ways of closing channel in goroutine have exactly the same effect?
As code snippets shown below. Sample I, closes channel inside goroutine; Sample II, closes in an anonymous goroutinue then call same logic
If these two have exactly the same effect, Does it mean chan is passed by reference?

Sample I

func Wakeup(wakeupChan chan<- int) {
    defer close(wakeupChan)
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    wakeupChan <- 1
}

func main() {
    wakeupChan := make(chan int)
    go Wakeup(wakeupChan)
    <-wakeupChan

    fmt.Println("wake up")
}


Sample II

func WakeupAnother(wakeupChan chan<- int) {
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    wakeupChan <- 1
}

func main() {
    wakeupChanAnother := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        defer close(wakeupChanAnother)
        WakeupAnother(wakeupChanAnother)
    }()
    <-wakeupChanAnother

    fmt.Println("wake up")
}


Functionally, yes, they both behave in the same way. The main difference is that you're wrapping the goroutine in an anonymous function, which is a bit pointless, and the channel therefore will be closed not when Wakeup returns, but rather when the anonymous function returns, so technically, it may close a tiny bit later - a really tiny bit, not really something you'd be able to measure. Although I said "it's a bit pointless" there are cases where the anonymous function could be argued to be the preferred approach, as the channel is created, and closed in the same function (effectively), whereas in the other example, you're creating a channel, passing it to the routine, and end up relying on that routine closing the channel correctly. If that function is bugged (e.g. the defer close(ch) winds up getting removed, it can lead to deadlocks
Compiler optimisation may even simplify the code to the same instructions, but you'd have to check the assembly for that.
As for the question about chan being passed as a reference: you can check the language spec on channel types. Seeing as a channel has a len and a cap (like a slice or map type) and an uninitialised channel's nil value is nil, to all intents and purposes, you can think of a channel as a reference type. That being said, the term "Reference type" is not really a thing in the go spec (it was removed 10 years ago with the commit message simply stating Go has no 'reference types'.
That said, in common parlance, reference types in go are generally used to refer to any type that, when uninitialised has a value of nil (that being pointers, slices, maps, interface and function variables, and indeed channels).
What I'd say about this particular question, though, is that channels are a native type in golang, specifically meant for communicating between multiple routines. The only way to achieve that is for the construct to have access to, or more accurately, share memory between sender and receiver, so passing a channel by definition means that you are referencing the same chunk of memory (so yeah, it's a "reference type" in that sense). If you were to implement a channel-like type yourself, you'd probably end up with something like this:
type Chan[T any] struct {
    data   []T
    mu     *sync.Mutex
    closed bool
}

func (c *Chan[T]) Send(v T) {
    c.mu.Lock()
    defer c.mu.Unlock()
    if c.closed {
        panic("Runtime panic: send on a closed channel")
    }
    c.data = append(c.data, v)
}

func (c *Chan[T]) Close() {
    c.mu.Lock()
    defer c.mu.Unlock()
    c.closed = true
}

func (c *Chan[T]) Recv() (T, bool) {
    var r T
    for {
        c.mu.Lock()
        closed := c.closed
        if len(c.data) == 0 {
            c.mu.Unlock() // release lock
            if !closed {
                // time.Sleep(time.Nanosecond) // wait a bit maybe
                continue // poll for next write to channel
            }
            return r, closed // return nil value + closed flag
        }
        t, c.data = c.data[0], c.data[1:] // get the oldest value for FIFO receive
        c.mu.Unlock() // release lock
        return t, closed // return value
    }
}

func (c *Chan[T]) Len() int {
    c.mu.Lock()
    defer c.mu.Unlock()
    return len(c.data)
}

Obviously, this is just some code I wrote up here, it's not perfect - or complete by any means. It's not using a fixed buffer size, for example (you would, in reality, probably use an array rather than a slice, and track the index to read from/write to using separate fields). The key takeway is that the methods use pointer receivers and are effectively accessing an array (a contiguous block of memory), which fits the description of what is commonly referred to as a reference type.
